# how to create file in aws S3 using python boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to create an empty file in AWS s3 using python.

I'm using boto3 and python.

I want to know apart from the put method is there any way to create files in s3?

Comment: Can I ask... _why_ do you want an empty file in an Amazon S3 bucket? There might be a better way of achieving your goal?

Comment: customer will send us .txt file and all the file names in one file(control file). so i have to validate whether data file and file names(in control file) are matching. if it is matching then program should generate one text file. it is kind of validation to ensure all the data files are received as per the control file..

Comment: @karthickbtech Hi, if the provided answer was helpful, please accept.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you genuinely want a zero-byte file, you can do it as follows:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

s3.put_object(
    Bucket='mybucket',
    Key='myemptyfile'
)
```

Note the lack of a `Body` parameter, resulting in an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **upload_file()** method :

```
s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_file(Filename = "file_name" , Key = "key")
```